Nestjs application not able to set cookie when deployed
I have a nestjs backend application, I'm setting 2 cookies (one httponly and other non http only cookie), The problem is the code works fine when on localhost (both frontend and backend on localhost)
When i host my backend on AWS ECS (fargate), frontends on same too, the cookie doesnt set on successful login.
My cookie domain is .domain.in, All my frontend and backend applications are subdomain.domain.in
Backend code for login
controller
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Get,
  Param,
  Post,
  Req,
  Response,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
//other imports

@Post('signin')
  async signin(
    @Body() command: Partial<SignInUserDto>,
    @Response({ passthrough: true }) res,
  ) {
    if (command.email) {
      const loginResponse = await this.commandBus.execute(
        new LoginUserWithEmailCommand(command.email, command.password),
      );
      this.assignCookieToResponse(res, loginResponse.access_token, {
        userId: loginResponse.userId,
        orgId: loginResponse.orgId,
        name: loginResponse.name,
      });
    } else {
      const loginResponse = await this.commandBus.execute(
        new LoginUserCommand(command),
      );
      this.assignCookieToResponse(res, loginResponse.access_token, {
        userId: loginResponse.userId,
        orgId: loginResponse.orgId,
        name: loginResponse.name,
      });
    }
    return res.send('cookie set');
  }

private assignCookieToResponse(
    response,
    accessToken: string,
    userCookieData,
  ) {
    const NODE_ENV = configService.getValue('NODE_ENV');
    const cookieExpiry = new Date(
      new Date().getTime() +
        configService.getValue('JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRY') * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    );
    response.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, {
      expires: cookieExpiry,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      domain: configService.getValue('COOKIE_DOMAIN'),
    });
    response.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(userCookieData), {
      expires: cookieExpiry,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
      domain: configService.getValue('COOKIE_DOMAIN'),
    });

    if (NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      response.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, {
        expires: cookieExpiry,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      response.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(userCookieData), {
        expires: cookieExpiry,
        sameSite: 'strict',
      });
    }

  }

I havent added SSL, because the only way to add ssl to ECS was to add it to ALB ( load balancer ), I have a hunch that it wouldn't work too because node backend and ALB might still communicate over HTTP (not sure of this)
Either ways i deployed setting secure: false in cookie setting, that didn't work too.
P.S. I am very sure that NODE_ENV env var is set to production and COOKIE_DOMAIN env var is set to .domain.in
On localhost the NODE_ENV is development.
